# How to make Iphone icon update notifier style icon

Tags: php, iphone, dreamweaver, photoshop

I'd like to make something similar what iPhone does with my icons. I'd like to have an icon and also the round red notifier in the upper right side of the icon for showing new updates.

[image]

How can I make it?

Comment: Is it just me or does the picture you posted look like an oldschool hologram you'd get with your chewing gum? awesome

Comment: Does the picture you have uploaded make sense AT ALL???

Comment: the picture is just to show the update icon, I mean the red round shape in the icon.

Comment: I hope it's okay that I put another screenshot to illustrate your wish.

Comment: It's perfect fluchtpunkt :) . I couldn't find any proper picture on google, but this is what I want to make thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those badges are handled through the OS.  You can't provide an icon with any content outside of the basic square.  To set the badge in the program look at the documentation for UIApplication and UILocalNotification.

Comment: Thanks Dancreek. 
btw, do you know any css or template that can make this for using in a web page?

Comment: Na, most of my experience is iOS based. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To get your application to display badge numbers, you can use something like this inside whatever method you want it to change the number.

```
int iBadgeNum = 5; //This variable will be read below
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:iBadgeNum];
```